# How to you inspect or look for .NET attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I have an enumeration for Status for a Task.  Some of the statuses are considered obsolete, and I have marked them as obsolete, as seen below:

```
public enum TaskStatus
{
    [Description("")]
    NotSet = 0,
    Pending = 1,
    Ready = 2,
    Open = 3,
    Completed = 4,
    Closed = 5,
    [Description("On Hold")][Obsolete]
    OnHold = 6,
    [Obsolete]
    Canceled = 7
}
```

In my user interface I populate a drop down with values on the enumerations, but I want to ignore ones that are marked as obsolete.  How would I got about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a LINQ-query:

```
var availableTaks = typeof (TaskStatus).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(f => f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (ObsoleteAttribute), false).Length == 0);
foreach(var task in availableTaks)
    Console.WriteLine(task);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Type enumType = typeof(testEnum);
enumType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Public)[i].GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

Then you can use your choice of method to loop through the array and checking if there are any custom attributes.

Comment: heh looks like I was real slow this time...the linq method is nice;-)

Comment: welcome and thank you...another neat usage of this I found was to store a display name...So you could display On Hold instead of OnHold. Also if you want to localize it then you just store the key for the resource file...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DebuggerHiddenAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute.aspx) and I know there is one that makes it hide from the properties explorer, but can't seem to remember the name.